# How to reset external protocol handler in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, reset, url, xdg-open

A while back I selected "Do nothing" when Chrome asked me how to handle a specific url. Now I want Chrome to launch xdg-open, which again can launch the correct application, but I can't figure out how to undo my "Do nothing" selection. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found a [solution](http://thetechjournal.com/how-to/tutorial-how-to-re-authorize-opening-of-external-applications-from-google-chrome.xhtml) to this on Windows, and it turns out it also works on Ubuntu:

1. Close Chrome
2. Open `~/.config/google-chrome/Local State` in a text editor.
3. Search for `protocol_handler`.
4. To make Chrome ask you how to handle a specific protocol again, remove the line corresponding to that protocol in the list of excluded schemes.
5. Save and exit.

**Update:** `protocol_handler` has been moved to the file `Preferences` in the subdirectory `Default`. If you are using multiple profiles, the file is also located in the folders `Profile 2`, `Profile 3` etc.

**Update:** `protocol_handler` no longer seems to exist, this is now handled directly within the Chrome settings, see https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0_FSBtFo5g_8 . Currently it is found in Settings -> Privacy and Security -> Site settings -> Handlers

Answer (score 5):

On Windows, this setting now appears to be located at

```
~/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Preferences
```

Do a search for `excluded_schemes`.  It will be a dictionary of custom protocol names set to `true` or `false`.  Find the desired custom protocol in the dictionary and delete that entry, save the file, then restart Chrome.