# Chrome opens files with wrong application

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with Google Chrome 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit) installed.

When I click on a file in the download section (chrome://downloads/), Chrome seems not to use my systems default application to open the file.
It always picks other applications.

If I click on "show in folder", Chrome opens Audacious.

Also I set JavaWS from JDK 8 as my default to open *.jnlp files but Chrome always uses JavaWS from JDK 6.

Other applications like Firefox use the right applications.

Is there something Chrome specific that I need to change as well, when I do changes at my default Applications?

Comment: Did you try to reset the auto-opening settings? It's at *Settings* > *Show advanced settings* > *Clear auto-opening settings*.

Comment: I don't see the "Clear auto-opening settings" Button in the settings. Maybe it was removed...

Comment: I'm running Chromium Version 51.0.2704.79 Ubuntu 16.04 and It is on the Downloads section. Is your system fully updated? `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: I'm running 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)

Comment: It should be a [button](http://static.commentcamarche.net/ccm.net/pictures/MnKodMZnp010yZBXjKmIaAK6hs0i12JKTmRgVh5phqDtWODKShO644zs0fkK7LA9-oto2-s-.png) under location select for Downloads.

Comment: please see edits. Note that I have Chrome not Chromium

Comment: This button is **only** visible when you have set any **auto-opening** setting. But this problem has nothing to do with **auto-opening**. Chrome just uses the **wrong application** for this mime-type.

Comment: Looks like I was sending you the wrong way. Auto opening settings are for the apps that you set to auto open upon download complete. Btw this button won't appear if you haven't selected an app to auto open after chrome downloads it. I've found 2 ways to go and solve your problem. 1 is answered [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/465597/246201) and if that doesn't work then you have to reconfigure the mime types for xdg-open

Comment: @PanagiotisTabakis: Lars wrote: `Other applications like Firefox use the right applications`, so I'm afraid **reconfigure the mime types** will not help (when firefox [and other applications] already uses the correct applicatons).

Comment: @Ben so we guess it's a Chrome-specific problem. [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/465597/246201) might do the trick.

Comment: @PanagiotisTabakis I removed the protocol in the file but it did not work. The applications chrome uses to open my files remain the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that Chrome uses xdg-open to open files.

I tried to open a file with xdg-open in the commandline. Which opened the same applications as Chrome did. So I viewed the output of xdg-open and found out, that xdg-open called gvfs-open, which was not installed on my system.

After installing it with `sudo apt-get install gvfs-bin` xdg-open (and Chrome) uses the right applications to open my files.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but with the same solution: [xdg-open stopped working...] http://askubuntu.com/a/816660/358044